# Insert and activate a phone number in a generated word document

Tags: c++, vba, ms-word, ms-office

I would like to add a phone number to a word document that I generate using the mso api.

In word, when one writes (Tel:00493298402938) and new line, the phone number is activated automatically.

While trying to record the corresponding macro and check the VBA code, it doesn't show the same behavior and the phone number is interpreted as a normal text.

Any helpful source code in VBA, C# or C++ is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Phone number is automatically activated? What you mean by that?

Comment: A hyperlink is created. In my case I have Microsoft Lync already installed, I can call directly the number from the word document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following code would be helpful to you?

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("A1"), "http://stackoverflow.com"
```

Just instead of the web address you would need the phone number.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it last time but it creates just an hyperlink. It doesn't redirect to lync or skype, ..

Comment: It worked, I had to add a lync addin in word and then the second parameter should be:"tel:00499348598" instead of just the phone number.